# Allow Outlook to display/download images from approved domains

Tags: exchange, group-policy, outlook

Outlook wisely does not automatically display/download images embedded in HTML emails.

Is there way to modify this policy site-wide (group policy or something), so everyone will see images that are from a whitelist of domains (think internal domains)?

I am specifically concerned about Exchange 2013 and Outlook 2010/2013, but the answer might apply to other versions.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  The "domain" you are referring to can be easily spoofed.

Comment: You are of course right.

Comment: Spoofed internal domains should be stopped by your server side spam filter. Preferably using DKIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook will auto download images for addresses in the Safe Senders list. You can push out a Safe Senders list to all clients via Group Policy and/or Registry settings.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2252421